# Generic Decodable Protocol Swift 4.2 unwrap optional error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

having issue with generic decodable protocol here, it seems that it returns optional unwrap error.  I am new to Swift but I don't know why it return optional.  See my code below:

```
public func requestGenericData<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, httpMethod: String, token: String) -> T? {
    var result: T?
    let fullStringUrl: String = self.url + urlString
    let urlReq = URL(string: fullStringUrl)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlReq!)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
    urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = httpMethod
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if self.isInternetAvailable() {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300 {
                    do {
                        let parsedObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                        result = parsedObj
                    } catch {
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))\n StatusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            showAlert(title: "No Internet Connect", message: "Please open your network and try again.", alertStyle: .alert, buttonTitle: "OK", buttonStyle: .default)
            return
        }
    }.resume()

    return result
}
```

**Update:** Error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: post the error you got , also this function is asynchronous result will always return optional nil

Comment: above only **urlReq!** that has ! , Does the error point to it or somewhere else , if so attach the other place

Answer (score 1):

You can update to this , check return whether true/false and then use the returned value

```
public func requestGenericData<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, httpMethod: String, token: String,completion:@escaping(_ result:T?,_ success:Bool)-> Void) {

    let fullStringUrl: String = self.url + urlString
    let urlReq = URL(string: fullStringUrl)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlReq!)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
    urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.httpMethod = httpMethod
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if self.isInternetAvailable() {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300 {
                    do {
                        let parsedObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                        completion(parsedObj,true)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))\n StatusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                         completion(nil,false)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            showAlert(title: "No Internet Connect", message: "Please open your network and try again.", alertStyle: .alert, buttonTitle: "OK", buttonStyle: .default)
             completion(nil,false)
        }
    }.resume()


}
```

//

call it

```
requestGenericData(urlString:<#url#>,httpMethod:<#httpMethod#>,token:<#token#>) { (result,success) in 

  if success {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` is an asynchronous method. Your `requestGenericData` function returns *before* `URLSession.dataTask` has even called its completion handler. Therefore, your `result` variable will still be `nil` when `requestGenericData` returns.

You need to make your function asynchronous as well. It should take a completion handler as a parameter and then call that from `URLSession.dataTask`'s completion handler.